# How do I change a character value in the format YYMMDD to a date format in PROC FEDSQL

Tags: sas

I want to change a column which is in the format YYMMDD (e.g. 130401 to mean 1st April, 2013), into a (numeric) date format. How do I do this in PROC FEDSQL?

In PROC SQL, I would use INPUT(DATE_COLUMN,YYMMDD6.) but I'm not sure how to do it for PROC FEDSQL

Comment: Is the existing variable NUMERIC or CHARACTER?  If it is numeric does it actually have numbers like yym,mdd or does it have actual date values and has the YYMMDDN6. format attached that i making it LOOK like YYMMDD.   Is the data in a SAS dataset or are you using FEDSQL to connect to some external database system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `inputn()` to convert it to a numeric SAS date, then [cast it to a date](https://go.documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/v_040/fedsqlref/n1fxzvj0otejpin15l3litfv4q62.htm) to change how it is displayed.

```
data foo;
    date_char = '130401';
run;

proc fedsql;
    select inputn(date_char, 'YYMMDD6.')::date as "date"
    from foo;
quit;
```

```
date
01APR2013
```